# How can we print pdf invoice through browser in odoo 10 without downloading?

Tags: xml, odoo, qweb

While generating invoice in odoo 10, invoice gets downloaded in pdf form. Instead of downloading, we need to print it from the printer directly through the browser without downloading in the first place. It should redirect to the printing page in browser. How can we do that in odoo 10? If anyone has done this then could u please guide us through?

Answer (score -1):

There are many modules in Odoo app store which shows the preview of the PDF instead of downloading it as an attachment. Most of this will open the pdf preview in a new tab and then you can decide whether to download, print or discard it. Some might give issues so try most of them and if you have some programming language try to see what is wrong in those modules if you get issues. Here is a [module](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/report_pdf_preview/) for Odoo 10 which should satisfy your requirement.

Comment: I've already done upto the preview but what i am trying to do is after clicking the print button it should open the browser printing page from where we can print the invoice without opening preview page. is there any way??

Comment: @zero This module for Odoo 11 seems to do what you explained i guess. But this is a paid module. https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/11.0/direct_print/